# trying to copy one file to the other one char at a a time

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy one file to another then read the other file but am not getting an output ,pls fix my code also I don't know how to use flush(),
I am inputting the name after that nothing is happening

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{char ss[20];
cout<<"enter name";
cin>>ss;
int len=strlen(ss);
fstream i_file;
i_file.open("data.txt",ios::in | ios::out);

for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    i_file.put(ss[i]);

} i_file.seekg(0);



    char c;

fstream o_file("new.txt");

while(!i_file.eof())
{   i_file.get(c);
    o_file.put(c);
}
i_file.flush();
o_file.flush();

char ch;
while(!o_file.eof()){
    o_file.get(ch);
    cout<<ch;
}
i_file.close();
o_file.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are your includes? Does your program compile? Does it run? Did you run it with your debugger?

Comment: In `while(!i_file.eof()) { o_file.put(c);}`, you don't modify `i_file`, `c` is used uninitialized. something like `i_file.get(c);` seems missing.

Comment: ok i edited it i_file.get(c); but there is no output still I have included iostream , stream and cstring

Comment: please post the complete code, the one you compile and execute and please describe what happens when you execute it. " not getting an output" means no file is created? Are you sure you are looking in the right directory? Or is a file created but it is empty?

Comment: ok i put the whole code, i just want the inputted name as the output but I am not getting  it

Comment: is the file created and empty? or is no `new.txt` created?

Comment: can you run the code on ur comp,

Comment: Your last loop to see content of "new.txt" starts at the end of file (no previous `o_file.seekg(0);`)

Comment: You should create sub functions `add_content_to_file(std::fstream&, const std::string&)`, `copy_content(std::fstream& src, std::fstream& dst)`, `std::string get_content(std::fstream&)`. You could then test each one separately.

Comment: One char at a time? Why not `char c; while (c = i_file.get()) o_file.put(c);`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ss[20];
    cout << "enter name:";
    cin >> ss;
    int len = strlen(ss);

    fstream i_file;
    i_file.open("data.txt", ios::out | ios::in | ios::trunc);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        i_file.put(ss[i]);
    }


    fstream o_file;
    o_file.open("new.txt", ios::out | ios::in | ios::trunc);

    char c;
    
    i_file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    i_file.get(c);
    while (!i_file.eof())
    {
        o_file.put(c);
        i_file.get(c);
    }
    
    o_file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    o_file.get(c);
    while (!o_file.eof()) {
        cout << c;
        o_file.get(c);
    }

    i_file.close();
    o_file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

if you will write it inside of the loop, so lets say the file `data.txt` contains "AB", so if you wrote the loop like this

```
while(!o_file.eof()){
    o_file.get(c);
    cout<<c;
}
```

it would first get "A" and then print, and then get "B" and print and then get o_file.eof and then try to print, so you want it to first get and then check and after you checked you can print, also for the file copying, you dont want it to copy the last character twice

a little simulation for what wrong on what you did
let's say again `i_file` is on the start of the file `data.txt`, and the file contains "AB", and `o_file` is empty,

```
while(!i_file.eof())
{
   i_file.get(c);
   o_file.put(c);
}
```

iteration 1:

````
/*
i_file.eof() returns false because file is on the start
so the sign ! opposite it to true
*/
while(!i_file.eof())

/*
c = 'A', because i_file on the start, and now i_file cursor is here A|B
(before reading B)
*/
i_file.get(c);

/*
now file ```new.txt``` contains the letter 'A'
*/
o_file.put(c);
````

iteration 2:

````
/*
i_file.eof() returns false because file is between A and B and not
on the end
so the sign ! opposite it to true
*/
while(!i_file.eof())

/*
c = 'B', because i_file cursor was between A and B, and now i_file cursor is after B (before reading EOF)
(before reading B)
*/
i_file.get(c);

/*
now file ```new.txt``` contains the letters "AB"
*/
o_file.put(c);
````

iteration 3:

````
/*
i_file.eof() returns false because file is **still** not read the end
so the sign ! opposite it to true
*/
while(!i_file.eof())

/*
c = 'B', because i_file cursor was before reading the EOF, and because there is no after B, c will still equal to B, and now i_file cursor is after reading EOF
*/
i_file.get(c);

/*
now file ```new.txt``` contains the letters "ABB"
because there is no if statement that checked that the i_file cursor is already in the EOF, and just when checking the next iteration, the loop will stop, thats why i put the .get out of the loop, or if you want you can just add an if statement inside the loop to check after you read from the file
*/
o_file.put(c);
````

Comment: thank you!! it worked, one ques why did you write     o_file.get(c) out of the loop

Comment: @rookie updated explanation in the answer ^^